# Kinect Calibration

Tags: kinect, camera-calibration

Using the Kinect for Windows SDK, what is the simplest way to calibrate the cameras?

I have found this lovely blog post http://nicolas.burrus.name/index.php/Research/KinectCalibration on the subject, but I'm curious if somebody knows an even simpler way.

Any hints, tipps and tricks are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"Calibrate the cameras"? If you're using the official SDK, you can get a mapping of which RGB pixel any particular depth pixel corresponds to.

See [this thread](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/kinectsdknuiapi/thread/40edbbc6-d0b1-4f14-b6a1-4a173c4dc588/) on the official support forum for a better explanation.

Answer (score 0):

Kinect has two cameras, RGB camera and IR camera.if you want to calibrate both,you need to take pics using both cameras.There are many software you can use,matlab calibration toolkit  and many other programming.you can calculate data easily.